# Sharepoint adding an item into a Picture Library

Tags: c#, sharepoint, file-io, wss

I would like to add an item into a picture Library using c#. This is how I would add a field to a normal item:

```
var item = list.Items.Add();
item["Title"] = "Item title";
item.Update();
```

How would I go about adding the picture? The picture is stored on the file system i.e. c:\myfile.png I iamgine I need to use SPFile but not sure how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a method to create a byte[] from the file

```
private byte [] StreamFile(string filename)
{
  FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);
  // Create a byte array of file stream length
  byte[] ImageData = new byte[fs.Length];
  //Read  block of bytes from stream into the byte array
  fs.Read(ImageData,0,System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
  //Close the File Stream
  fs.Close();
  return ImageData;
}

// then use the following to add the file to the list
list.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileName, StreamFile(fileName));
```

Comment: How would I then go about and set the fields on the item?

Comment: Just need to add a hashtable to the list.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileName, StreamFile(fileName));

Comment: The Files.Add Method returns an SPFile object. You can then use SPFile.Item to fill in the fields. ie. SPFile file= list.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileName, StreamFile(fileName));
SPListItem item = file.item;
item["Field" = somevalue;

Answer (score 1):

It is as simple as adding a file to the Document Lib. Below is the code snippet that will help you do it. I have take the code from the this [link](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/29565-Uploading-images-into-picture-library.aspx) as the formatting is not proper there I pasted a clean version here

```
try
        {
            byte[] imageData = null;
            if (flUpload != null)
            {
                // This condition checks whether the user has uploaded a file or not
                if ((flUpload.PostedFile != null) && (flUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0))
                {
                   Stream MyStream = flUpload.PostedFile.InputStream;
                   long iLength = MyStream.Length;
                   imageData = new byte[(int)MyStream.Length];
                   MyStream.Read(imageData, 0, (int)MyStream.Length);
                   MyStream.Close();
                   string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(flUpload.PostedFile.FileName);                                                
                   SPPictureLibrary pic = (SPPictureLibrary)SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["Images"];//Images is the picture library name
                   SPFileCollection filecol = ((SPPictureLibrary)SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["Images"]).RootFolder.Files;//getting all the files which is in picture library
                   filecol.Add(filename, imageData);//uploading the files to picture library
                    
                }
            }                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //handle it
        }
```